# How can I do an inverse LIKE on SQL on php?

Tags: php, sql

I want to select a value from a database in sql with php. So, the value that I want to select is a part of the value which I compare it with.

There are two tables: one is called event and the other weekly. In the table event, there is a column called name, that is the name of each event. Weekly has also a column called name, and it´s the name of the weekly. So, I want to get the id from a weekly comparing the two names. But the name of the event can have something before and/or after the name. For example:

```
Weekly name: Monday

Weekly id: 1

Event: NJK Monday 3


Another example:

Weekly name: Tuesday

Weekly id: 2

Event: Tuesday ks
```

I´ve tried to do it with a LIKE condition, but I didn´t earn the result that I wanted.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE db.event SET weeklyid ="
                    . " (SELECT id FROM db.weekly WHERE %name%"
                    . " LIKE  'NJK Monday 3') WHERE name = :name;");
            $stmt->bindValue('name', $event->name);
            $stmt->execute();
```

So, it´s like an inverse LIKE. The result that I want to get from the code above would be that the select sentence return 1.

Comment: Its been a while but shouldn't it be `%:name%` with the `:`

Comment: The inverse of LIKE would be NOT LIKE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT()` to add the `%` symbols around the attribute like this

```
SELECT id FROM db.weekly WHERE 'NJK Monday 3' LIKE CONCAT('%', name, '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it works with named placeholders by if you will use `?` placeholder you should add `%` to execute values not to query:

**wrong**

```php
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id FROM db.weekly WHERE name LIKE %?%');
$stmt->execute(['NJK Monday 3']);
```

**good**

```php
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id FROM db.weekly WHERE name LIKE ?');
$stmt->execute(['%NJK Monday 3%']);
```